# Great work life balance, boring work

Tags: job-change, work-life-balance, boredom

For the past 7 years I've been part of a company that provides great work life balance & pretty good compensation.

When I joined there was a lot of interesting work to do & it was perfect.
Now, a lot of the bigger projects are complete & I have to find work for myself a lot. I end up on projects i wouldnt otherwise get exposure to which is great, but overall i feel ive stopped moving.

I could just move right now but:

- work life balance is great and with two very young kids, i get to spend a lot more time with them, which would not happen in another organization.
- The package is quite good and although I could do better, it would not be by much & living in Europe, most of it would be eaten by tax.
- Most jobs in my field are in consultancy & come with travel & a lot more hours, eroding family time.

There is also the risk of not moving which is:

- stagnation -  I work in IT so its easy to fall behind modern tech and techniques.
- mental health - its just not good for a person to be bored & think they're at a dead end.

Would appreciate some alternative viewpoints to provide me with different perspective of the situation.

**Update 1:**

Based on replies raising good questions, i am adding the following details:

I was in this exact state 3 years ago & handed in my notice but was not happy about it or the new role i was going to.
Management worked with me to help give me responsibilities and a role i would be happy doing. They show a high level of empathy & kindness, another reason I am not happy about leaving.

In the 3 years since, most of the projects we attempted to get the organization moving in a more data driven direction didnt not come to fruition, mainly because of company culture, hoarding of data, unwilling to see a bigger picture.

I have since had a similar discussion with my managers, stating this, that we tried to carve a new role out but the org is not ready for that level of change. My managers have shown the same empathy as before and say they are working to find and help me push projects valuable to the org that also align with my goals.
This was true until recently and the risk aversion to data projects got a voice on the IT Management team.

As mentioned by @Alan Dev, i probably know i need to move on but need to get over the fear.

Comment: Have you talked about those needs with your immediate manager? Does your company offer a personal development budget or other type of skill improvement opportunities?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like you know the answer and just want re-assurance!  If you have enough to live on then take this time with your family  - it's precious and you will never get it back!

As they grow money might become more important and you can think about a move then. Just ensure you keep aware of developments in the market, see if you maybe do some POCs with new techology in your current role.

Answer (score 0):

> stagnation - I work in IT so its easy to fall behind modern tech and techniques.

That should NOT be the case. If you fall behind, so will the company and if the company falls behind it's not sustainable.

You have a good gig going, and it's in both your AND your companies interest that you stay sharp, engaged and up to date on the state of the art and new technologies.

It's time to engage the powers at be. The best strategy depends a lot on the details of your company and the cast of characters involved but typically follows these steps

1. Describe the current state (here is what we are doing)
2. State the problem with the current state (things are great now, but in 5 years they won't be because of XYZ). Describe the future state, if no changes are made. Focus business impact and consequences, lost revenue, inability to attract talent, slow and cumbersome processes, falling behind competitors
3. Describe the future state. Show how it addresses the problem and how it's sustainable
4. Propose an action plan that leads to the future state. If you can: specific milestones, check points, deliverables, timeline, budget, etc.

In line 4, you can make sure that there is plenty of interesting things for you to work in. This could even be a stepping stone for a leadership position, if you sell it well and are put in charge of implementing (if that's what you want).

Comment: ive updated the original post with some extra detail

Comment: I know many companies that fell behind and still survived. Hell I have been working at a firm that doesnt use ANY frameworks or modern technologies. Just plain HTML, CSS and Javascript and they are doing really well. 
A friend of me just switched jobs because he was also stuck at an old school firm who basically still codes in VB, which is unnecessary. They offered 300% of his salary if he stayed because they were doing good. 
You CAN fall behind as a person and companies can survive on 1990 tech